# PHP timezone conversion issue

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, date-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

I have this function which is used to covert request date into GMT00 unix time span and store that time span into database.

When i am trying to convert GMT00 time span to valid GMT timezone like GMT+4:00 then below function return wrong time span

```
/**
     * Convert date time from one timezone to another timezone
     *
     * @param $datetime (string): Date Time value which needs to be converted
     * @param $is_timestamp (boolean): If $datetime is a timestamp then true, otherwise false
     * @param $stimezone (string): Timezone from which to convert date and time
     * @param $dtimezone (string): Timezone in which to convert date and time
     * @param $format (string): Format in which you need date and time
     *
     * @return (misc) Converted date time string, null on failure
     */
```

```
public static function convertDateTime($datetime, $is_timestamp = false, $stimezone = "GMT+00:00", $dtimezone = "GMT+00:00", $format = null) {
    if ($is_timestamp) {
        $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);

    } else {
        $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime));
    }

    try {
        $date = new \DateTime($datetime, new \DateTimeZone($stimezone));
        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($dtimezone));

        if (!empty($format)) {
            //return $date->format($format);
            return gmdate($format, $date->getTimestamp());

        } else {
            return $date->getTimestamp();
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `convertDateTime('2017-09-12 22:45:23', false, "GMT+00:00", "GMT+04:00");` gives normal result, can you please specify what you call "wrong time span" ?

Comment: The main logic here is that we passed request date as date object and then it will convert it into GMT00 timespan,when i am calling that function at the time of update operation, i have timespan value as i get that timespan from database.so at the update time i called convertDatetime function like, convertDateTime(GMT00timepsan,true,GMT00,GMT+4:00)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that line: `return gmdate($format, $date->getTimestamp());`

**The timestamp does not carry the timezone.** The unix timestamp is the number of seconds spent since the 1st of January 1970 at midnight, UTC. **It is the same, no matter the timezone.** So when you use `$date->getTimestamp()` you 'lose' the timezone metada of the `$date` object.

So you can fix your code by modifying

```
return gmdate($format, $date->getTimestamp());
```

by

```
return $date->format($format);
```

I hope this helps.